# Why can't I Add Vector Asset (SVG) to Android Studio Project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, svg, vector-graphics

I'm trying to add a Vector Asset (SVG) to my Flutter Android project, but all the directions I'm finding online aren't working.

What I'm reading says there's supposed to be a process from Android Studio that lets me add an asset like:

1. right click on drawable folder
2. New -> Vector Asset

I also made changes to my gradle.build file. However, I don't seem to have the option to add a Vector Asset and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**gradle.build**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        generatedDensities=[]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

[image: Picture of what I see in Android Studio]

What am I missing or how to import an SVG asset to be a drawable in Android?

Comment: is it a `flutter` issue? if so, what do you mean by: *"Does anyone know what I'm missing or how to import an SVG asset to be a drawable in Android?"*?

Comment: Thanks @pskink for your time. It turns out to be not a Flutter issue, it's an Android library support issue. The Vector Asset manager in Android requires a higher level of Android than my project (professional) was supporting. I had to try it out in a different project/environment to realize the issue with adding Vector Assets in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has to be 5.0+ or higher to support Vector Assets.

An alternative solution is to take vector assets and turn them into a high resolution PNG, and 9 patch the images and create drawable layers (this was for a splash page with XML configuration for the layout).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Asset Studio window by opening you repository's `<your_repo_name>/android` directory in Android Studio, then the New -> Vector Asset will be an option.